# Vue.js router not calling beforeRouteUpdate (typescript)

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a component that contains router-links to the same route, but with a different parameter. When navigating to those links, the url changes but the data isn't updating. I have *beforeRouteUpdate* defined, but it is never called.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
@Component
export default class AccountComponent extends Vue {
    address: string;
    account: Account;

    data() {
        return {
            account: null
        }
    }

    beforeRouteUpdate(to: any, from: any, next: any) {
        console.log('beforeRouteUpdate for ' + to.params.address);
        next();
    }

    mounted() {
        this.address = this.$route.params.address;
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData() {
        console.log('Fetching data for ' + this.address);
        fetch('api/Account/Get?address=' + this.address)
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<Account>)
            .then(data => {
                this.account = data;
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just ran into this issue myself 2 years after the question was asked but in addition to Simsteve7's answer I need to place that code inside it's own file

```
// router/componentHooks.ts

import Component from "vue-class-component";

// Register the router hooks with their names
Component.registerHooks([
    "beforeRouteEnter",
    "beforeRouteLeave",
    "beforeRouteUpdate"
]);
```

Then over in main.ts the very first line you import that in.

```
import './router/componentHooks' // <-- Needs to be first
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
```

Before I just had the component's calls within mounted and was getting the slug through this.$route.params. Instead of that I put everything within mounted in it's own function and then called that from mounted using this.$route.params and beforeRouteUpdate's to.params. So for an example:

```
  async mounted() {
        await this.loadPage(this.$route.params.id)
  }

  async beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
        console.log(`beforeRouteUpdate ${to.params.id}`)
        await this.loadPage(to.params.id)
    next()
  }

  async loadPage(id) {
    //...
  }
```

Sources: https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/additional-hooks.html

Answer (score 6):

Since there is still no answer, I'll post a possible issue.

Make sure to register the `beforeRouteUpdate` hook before initializing Vue.

```
Component.registerHooks([
    'beforeRouteEnter',
    'beforeRouteLeave',
    'beforeRouteUpdate',
]);

new Vue({...});
```

Comment: in index.ts rather than .vue file??

Comment: Thank you Erik and Simsteve7, that helped. First I thought the issue in SSR that I've used and tried to search info on VueRouter docs. But then I found this question and understood that the issue is in the typescript (also described here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component#adding-custom-hooks )

Answer (score 0):

If someone ends up here using > `vue-class-component@^8.0.0-rc.1` the following code can be used:

```
import { Vue } from "vue-class-component";

Vue.registerHooks([
    "beforeRouteEnter",
    "beforeRouteLeave",
    "beforeRouteUpdate"
]);
```